# Open distro for elasticsearch Document-level security

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

First of all, I apologize for my weakness in English.

I'm developing Open Distro for Elasticsearch (V7.9).
I have set Document-level security for Role, but I get an error.
The sample code in the Open Distro documentation also shows the error.

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Saved object [config/7.9.1] not found"}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue after setting the security role. did you find the solution? I'm using AWS elastic search/kiana